# Geolocation-based Domain Name Resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, powerdns, powerdns-recursor

Can I have Geolocation-based Domain Name Resolution in PowerDNS cluster?

I have to make a PowerDNS cluster for my project and there is a requirement of Geolocation-based Domain Name Resolution.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be right in the documentation, no?

https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/backends/geoip.html

> This backend (which is a.k.a. the YAML backend) allows visitors to be sent to a server closer to them, with no appreciable delay, as would otherwise be incurred with a protocol level redirect. Additionally, the Geo Backend can be used to provide service over several clusters, any of which can be taken out of use easily, for example for maintenance purposes. This backend can utilize EDNS Client Subnet extension for decision making, if provided in query and you have turned on edns-subnet-processing.

Comment: I see my bad! i didn't elaborated i am indicating not towards dns servers being geoip located but using Powerdns to geoip my webservers. just like amazon route 53 have a geoip,

is this what is being indicated in documentation or i am missing something? I assume that i am not being wrong if you are satisfied then please guide me :)

Comment: we will not provide any learning material as it is offtopic, if you need to have a GeoIP location service for your webserver they use google, cloudflare, or something like this.

Comment: @Rohanbatrame Look at the LUA backend for any advanced feature. But other than that your question is too vague, and just asking for remote references is kind of offtopic here. Please see https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Rohanbatrame You say "but using Powerdns to geoip my webservers." documentation says " allows visitors to be sent to a server closer to them," isn't that a direct immediate match in feature to what you need?